# Wordpress site with subdomain without multisite installation

Tags: subdomains

We have a wordpress site say **www.example.com** with more than 1k users. Now I wanted to enable subdomains to some premium category users, that is for who opted for their own subdomains. So that, if user enters **u1.example.com** should function similar to **www.example.com**

Wordpress multisite is one of the possibility but we don't want multisite architecture right now (as multisite will create separate database tables which is not in our scope) since all other different type of user allocations are already functioning and cannot be redesigned for time being and so is there any other ways to accomplish it?

**EDIT:** Some hooks or .htaccess file is more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a way to redirect users to a certain page or post if a specific url is given.

Try one of these plugins (in a staging environment if possible - if not, backup!):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/subdomain

Comment: We are interested in either some hooks or .htaccess configurations. Cannot integrate plugins.